Edit ListBox Values Directly From MySql Workbech
I have a listbox that pulls data from MySQL Workbench through a selection from the combobox. Each of the rows of the pulled data has an auto increment ID. I have code that sends the values of a selected row into assigned text box.
Now I want to edit the Qty in the textbox, then update it directly in the listbox by using the auto increment ID as reference before updating it in MYSQL Workbench.
Private Sub btn_Update_Sales_Click()
   Dim r As Integer

   With frmUpdateSales.ListBox3
       For r = 0 To .ListCount - 1
           If .List(r, 0) = frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value Then
               .AddItem
               .List(r, 6) = frmUpdateSales.txt_Qty.Value
           End If
       Next r
   End With
End Sub



Your code is nearly complete. You don't need to use .AddItem since you are attempting to modify data in existing items.

Private Sub btn_Update_Sales_Click()
    Dim r As Integer
    With frmUpdateSales.ListBox3
        For r = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Debug.Print frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value, Len(frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value), .List(r, 0), Len(.List(r, 0))
            If .List(r, 0) = frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value Then
                .List(r, 6) = frmUpdateSales.txt_Qty.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub


Ops. I change the quantity values alright buy it does not get updated in the listbox, I don't even get an error message

pls try to test the code with const. eg.  If .List(r, 0) = 1 Then :  .List(r, 6) = 55

When i tested the code with constant figures it updated alright but when i assign the list variable to the textboxes, it does not update. i find this strange

Please validate the content of textbox which is used in If clause. eg. Debug.Print frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value, Len(frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value) I suspect there is a non-printable character in it.

how do i do that please? i mean where do i place the code debug.print.........

When i convert my textbox value into a numerical value like this 'Val(frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value)', it works perfectly and gets the unit column of the listbox updated

When i convert my textbox value into a numerical value like this        'Val(frmUpdateSales.txtTransactn_ID.Value) ', it works perfectly and gets the unit column of the listbox updated

Add deugging code line as the snippet in my answer. Val function removes some leading non-printable chars. eg. val(vbCr & " 12abc " & vbCr) returns 12.
